# Switching focus between multiple modal dialogs

Tags: java, swing

is it possible to switch the focus between two modal dialogs? That is, one dialog has the focus and is interactive and I switch the focus/interactivity to the other dialog. Here's my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    final JDialog dialog1 = new JDialog(frame, true);
    dialog1.setContentPane(new JLabel("dialog 1"));
    dialog1.pack();
    dialog1.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dialog1.setVisible(true);
        }
    }).start();
    final JDialog dialog2 = new JDialog(frame, true);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
    dialog2.setContentPane(btn);
    dialog2.pack();
    dialog2.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dialog2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Can I put anything where the TODO is to give dialog1 the focus? I've tried `toFront`, `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`, and `grabFocus`, and none of them do the trick. They will bring dialog1 to the front, but dialog2 is still the interactive one.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Have you tried `requestFocus()` ?

Comment: @Eng: That won't work. The design sounds funky. Why not instead swap views via CardLayout.

Comment: Or a `JTabbedPane` or `JToolBar` or two non-modal dialogs or some design context.

Comment: The use case involves a progress bar dialog. The progress dialog is shown on a new thread. Meanwhile, the user is presented with a modal dialog for some input. So, we fire off a thread that will ultimately show a progress dialog, then go ahead and show the input dialog. When the progress dialog shows, it occasionally will pop over the input dialog. Since the progress dialog is set up to not be closeable, the user gets stuck. It sounds like maybe we need to redesign how the progress dialog is shown rather than trying to fix something that sounds difficult (or impossible) to fix.

Comment: Does the progress dialog have to be modal? I don't know about all the details of your use case, but it sounds unnecessary to me. I would make a dialog modal only if you need input from the user.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. At the end of the day, we decided to change the progress dialog to be non-modal. If we want to block user input to any window when the progress dialog is showing, we use its glass pane. Otherwise, a modal dialog will get focus precedence over the progress dialog (since it is non-modal). In this way, we can control *when* to block user input and avoid getting the users stuck. Also, if we pop a modal dialog while another modal dialog is already showing, we make sure the new dialog is parented by the existing dialog.